# my wordpress plugin ajax method no run php method and return 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I got other ajax methods working properly and I follow same steps for this one but it is even no runing php method.

```
/*
* Enqueue plguin's script
*/
function assing_store_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('assignStore', plugins_url( 'store-assign/assign.js', dirname(__FILE__)), array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('getUserStores', plugins_url( 'store-assign/assign.js', dirname(__FILE__)), array('jquery'));

    // ---- This one is ----- 
    wp_enqueue_script('getStoreSettings', plugins_url( 'store-assign/assign.js', dirname(__FILE__)), array('jquery'));
    // -------- End ---------

    wp_enqueue_script('postStoreSettings', plugins_url( 'store-assign/assign.js', dirname(__FILE__)), array('jquery'));
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'assing_store_scripts' );
```

This is the JS method on "assign.js" file:

```
/*
 * Action when click on Franchisee's Store on Franchisee Settings Panel
 */
jQuery('ul#listUserStore').on('click', '.MyStore', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    var label = jQuery('#assigned-label span.description');

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'getStoreSettings',
            StoreID: $this.data('storeid')
        },
        success: function(data){
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(obj);

            /*if(obj == 'true'){
                label.css('display', 'block').css('color', 'green');
                label.text('Store selected has been assigned to ' + name);
                jQuery("#user_store option[value='" + storeID + "']").remove();
                jQuery( '#select_USER').change();

            } else {
                label.css('display', 'block').css('color', 'red');
                label.text('Store selected has not been assigned to the user selected. Please contact with the administrator.');
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
                label.css('display', 'none')
            }, 5000);*/
        }
    });
});
```

And this is the php call back ajax method. In this example is just a response of varible POST just to test but I can't get the response. I'm getting always zero "0" instead.

```
/*
 * Ajax
 * Get Franchisee's Store Settings
 */
function getStoreSettings() {
    global $wpdb;

    echo json_encode($_POST);
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_getUserStores', 'getStoreSettings');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action on ajax submit is `getStoreSettings` while the action you define on `wp_ajax_` is `getUserStores`, it returns 0 because no action found hook on `wp_ajax_` as your request is looking for the action `wp_ajax_getStoreSettings` which you never define

Do it like this

ajax data

```
data: {
    'action': 'getStoreSettings',
    'StoreID': $this.data('storeid')
},
```

Ajax function

```
function getStoreSettings() {
    global $wpdb;
    wp_send_json( $_REQUEST );
}
add_action('wp_ajax_getStoreSettings', 'getStoreSettings');
```

Additionally you should add nonce verification to make it secure,

Comment: OMG!! It was the hook call as you said!! For this method I did copy-paste everything and change necessary things but I forgot that one. Many thanks bro. And thanks for the suggest about nonce verification, definetly I have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

your `add_action` should be

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_getStoreSettings', 'getStoreSettings' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_getStoreSettings', 'getStoreSettings' );
```

Comment: Only if this is for a front end facing ajax request. Otherwise the nopriv shouldn't be included.

Comment: Thanks man it was that! I'm not using this method for front-end at all.

Comment: I can't because Symmetrics Web response was wrote earlier than yours, so I fixed my issue with them first. After that, I saw your resposne and I wrote you just to be polite. If the systems let me select more than one response, I would, but I can't. Sorry mate.

Comment: @CarlosDiaz actually I answered first. Look at the times.

Comment: Well, then you have to ask to the administrator why your answer is appearing after an older one when it has to be cronologically ordered. I marked the first correct answer I saw that it wasn't yours.